# Craft Commerce: Addresses not showing in profile

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I have recently added the Customer Info field to user profiles for the CP. I noticed however that the recorded addresses for the user are not listed. I checked against the order and there is addresses associated with it. Is there something I need to be doing to enable the address to show?

See screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried looping through the users addresses in a front-end template?

Comment: What version of Commerce? (Find in Settings->Plugins and look at your Commerce verision). There was a bug related to this a while back that was fixed. See https://craftcommerce.com/changelog#build1179 Additional updates have also fixed things related to customer addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Its likely that the order was made while a guest user, then signed up, so the guest order was then associated with the new user - but the addresses used in that guest order don't get copied to the address book of the new user.

Comment: They do get copied to the new user if CROC is used for registration - https://github.com/bossanova808/CommerceRegisterOnCheckout